# What is Successor Value Pattern

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I am reading scala in action (manning edition) and there is a chapter on this pattern with a code sample:

```
class PureSquare(val side: Int) {
def newSide(s: Int): PureSquare = new PureSquare(s)
def area = side * side
}
```

The book has a link supposed to explain the pattern. Unfortunately, the link is broken and I can't find it.

Would someone be able to explain this pattern and how this piece of code is supposed to work?

Because I don't see how newSide is called when calling the area function.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right: `newSide` doesn't directly change the `area`, but it creates a new `PureSquare` with a different `side` length.

It's meant to show how to work with *purely functional* objects (with no mutable internal state) while coping with the need to make changes within our program

Using this pattern any object you create remains technically *immutable* but you can "simulate" changing the object by calling the proper method (in this case `newSide`)

An example worth 100 explanations

```
val square1 = new PureSquare(1)
assert(square1.area == 1)

//this is similar to changing the side of square1
val square2 = square1.newSide(2)

//and the area changes consequently
assert(square2.area == 4)
//while the original call is still referentially transparent [*]
assert(square1.area == 1)
```

[*] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)

Comment: OK so each time you want to change the side, you have to call newSide which actually creates a new object, making the object immutable. thanks for your answer!

Comment: @unludo But anything with a reference to the old version will not see a change.  This is actually seen as a good thing, since it allows sane concurrency, avoids synchronisation deadlocks and so on.